# Computation of $k$ dominant right singular vectors without SVD computation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd, singular-values

I have a maxtrix ${\bf A} \in \mathcal{C}^{m \times n}$, where $m < n$. However, the $m$ and $n$ are large numbers (for eg: m = 50, n = 250). I need to find the $k$ dominant right singular vectors of ${\bf A}$, where $k$ can be smaller than the rank of the ${\bf A}$.

Now, computing SVD can be computational complex. Is there any method to compute $k$ dominant right singular vectors for ${\bf A}$.

I know the dominant singular vector can be computed using the power iteration method but what can be done if we need to kind $k$ dominant right singular vectors.

Comment: There are canned routines for this, see for example the 'svds' function in Matlab. But otherwise, you can use the property that $v_n$ is an argmax of $\| Av \|^2_2$ over unit vectors $v$ which are orthogonal to $v_1,\dots,v_{n-1}$. Thus you have a constrained optimization problem,, which you can try to solve using optimization methods (generally avoiding the construction of $A^*A$ or $A A^*$, though). In practice I think programs like 'svds' are more sophisticated than that, however.

Comment: With that said, this problem is rather small computationally speaking, so unless you need to do this problem in a matter of milliseconds, it's going to be just fine to assemble the entire reduced SVD.